# Why would $.getJSON fail when JSON passes jslint.com test?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am using this

```
    $.getJSON('localhost/api/getStoreInventory', data, function(json) {});
```

to make a json call to an api I'm working on. This will work fine as long as I use localhost, once I change it to my product server ex:

```
    $.getJSON('http://mydomain.com/api/getStoreInventory', 
              data, function(json) {});
```

the call will fail. Both api files on localhost and production are identical. I ran the json that my api returns through the JSLint.com json verifier and it reports my json is good with the default settings. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Define "fail", if you would please

Comment: It's a classic :) Go with JSONP if you need to do cross domain calls.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't make cross domain ajax requests.

http://usejquery.com/posts/9/the-jquery-cross-domain-ajax-guide

Comment: I think you are right on this. This is the only thing that makes sense because everything else is exactly the same. Thans

Comment: Yeah. The full URL gives it away :). There are ways around the restriction, the link I posted gives some examples. Some I've used and some I haven't. I most commonly use the server-side proxy method.

Comment: Many browsers support CORS nowadays, including IE. I wouldn't go as far as to state that you *can't* do cross-domain requests, just that there isn't any support in old browsers.

Comment: That was the problem, I got around this by implementing JSONP on the api side. Thanks for the help.